# How to address "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors, Stability and security will suffer" in HeadlessChrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to run chrome headless using selenium in C# but I keep getting this error:

[image]

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag:
>   --ignore-certificate-errors, Stability and security will suffer.

I'm using

- Chrome: 61
- ChromeDriver: 2.3
- Selenium: 3.6
- .Net 4.5

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace MyApp {
public partial class Form1: Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        IWebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--window-size=1440,900");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
}
}
```

My WinForm application just has one button with name "StartBtn".

Comment: you might want to try using phantomjs instead.

Comment: @RichBryant Chrome is more stable and better in performance than PhantomJs.

Comment: debatable.  phantom does tend to play rather more nicely with command line options.

Comment: We need full re-creation steps here.

Comment: @Liam Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Tell us how we can also get this error message. i.e. create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without all the information on how to re-create this issue no one can help

Comment: @Liam Updated with my complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the following error :

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors, Stability and security will suffer

As you are using **`Selenium: 3.6`** along with **`Chrome: 61`**, instead of using **`chromedriver v2.3`** consider using the latest version of the **`chromedriver.exe`** i.e. **`v2.33`**

Additionally, along with your existing arguments add the following arguments as well: **`disable-infobars`**, **`--disable-extensions`**

So, the line of code will be as follows:

```
options.AddArguments("headless", "disable-gpu", "remote-debugging-port=9222", "window-size=1440,900", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions")
```

Comment: Updated my Answer with versioning info. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following was what i did to resolve similar issue

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
```

The following is the whole code just to open url that worked , hope its helpful

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");// this is the one that helped
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("Google is selected");
```