# How to hide browser selenium when its running c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Can i hide the browser when its running?

I mean i want to a user pass [Im not a robot] reCaptCha themself when login! After login, the browser will hide and running in background! Can i?

```
 ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
 ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
 service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service,option);

 driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://xxx.xxx/login");

 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("https://xxx.xxx/")); // login success and browser will hide, running in background.
```

Comment: You can use chrome headless with selenium, see this question for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789261/headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-c-sharp

Comment: @RandomStranger i know that, but if i run it headless at the begin, i cant make user verify human because reCaptCha dont appear

Comment: why do you want to hide the browser?

Comment: @Murthi i want to create a automation get data from my account in xxx.xxx (hide), if i dont hide, people maybe know my account information

Answer (score 1):

I am using code like this:

```
IWebDriver driver;    
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can run chrome headless after it starts (make it close and run without a UI in the middle of the run).

BUT

You might be able to achieve what you want if you login with your browser open, and save your cookies (the cookies generated from you being logged in), and then import them to a new headless driver.

That way, you can still login with a UI, and have the session ready do the rest of what you want to do with a browser UI closed.

Take a look at [this](https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html). It contains information about Cookie Handling in selenium.